# React Realm slow rendering with Object.keys

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I just got into optimizing and I noticed that one of my component takes ~250ms to render, even though its just a simple Picker. The Code looks like this.

```
type PickerProps = {
  value: string;
  setValue: (value: string) => void;
  units: Realm.Results<Units & Realm.Object>;
};

const PickerWithPortion: React.FC<PickerProps> = props => {
  const { value, setValue, units } = props;
  return (
    <Picker selectedValue={value} onValueChange={value => props.setValue(value)}>
      {Object.keys(units).map((value, index) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={units[index].id.toString()} label={units[index].shortName} value={units[index].shortName} />;
      })}
    </Picker>
  );
};
```

I am guessing this is connected to lazy loading. The Picker only contains ~4 items. What should I do ? That realm data is being used across the app but MIGHT change later. Should I store it in redux and keep it in sync with realm or is there something that I am missing ? Other components that use Realm.Results aren't taking nearly as long as this component.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I could use [React.Profiler](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html) and wrapped my Picker with this. Without Debugging enabled the Component only took ~20ms. So I guess Realm is only really, really slow when you have Debugging enabled. Hopefully I could help some other helpless fool avoid trying to optimize a Component that is fine as is.